# How do I make it so that pymysql doesn't hang when querying my rds database?

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, pymysql

I set up an EC2 instance on Amazon Web Services.
I create an RDS database service with all the proper tables in it.
I log into the EC2 instance and git pull my codebase.
I run the python code which uses pymysql to connect to the database and when sending an sql request the program just hangs on that line of code.

I tried simply running my program on this EC2 instance.

```py
def get_list_of_dictionaries_with_select(select_statement):
    conn = get_new_mysql_connection()
    cursor = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    cursor.execute(select_statement)
    return_value = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
    return return_value
```

When I stop python I realize that the program is stuck on the cursor.execute(select_statement) line of code.

Normally the python program would not get stuck (like when I run it on my macintosh laptop), but in this case it gets stuck on cursor.execute when I run it in the cloud.

Comment: what is your security group configuration?

Comment: What is your `select_statement`?